# NAudio on Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, naudio

Is it possible to use the NAudio on a silverlight application? 
I just can't add the dll to my project... I'd like to build a little audio mixer.

I already searched on google but i can't find a way to do that...

someone has  some hints for it???

Answer (score 3):

NAudio uses tons of interop into Win32 functions that would be completely impossible to run in Silverlight.

---

UPDATE:

If you are looking for an MP3 player for Silverlight you may check out the [Silverlight Audio Player](http://slaudioplayer.codeplex.com/).

Comment: any hint on how can I manipulate music files to speed them up and stuff live on silverlight?

Comment: @Killercode, please be more specific: what music formats you would like to support, what does *speed them up* and *stuff live* means, what exactly you would like to do with them? Remember that the more information you provide, the better answers you will get.

Comment: I would like to change the tempo of the music to make it run faster... also I would like to support mp3, live is doing it at the moment of the playback